# Comment date stamp does not update when page is refreshed

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, android-app

I had a question open in the Android app (version 1.0.66) and then returned to the app hours later. I pulled down to refresh the page and saw a new comment appear, but the old comment still says it was just posted. The image below explains it better (click for full resolution).

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this on the latest version of the app.